# Found Old D Code That Needs Update

Tags: d, dmd

While digging around the internet in search of a tool that would allow me to extract sound files from a Java container, I found a 4+ year old bit of D code. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to compile, and discovered upon searching Google that std.stream had been deprecated. I have never worked with D before now, however, and I can't find any clear-cut ideas on how to bring this pre-stream-death code up to speed. Are there any current D programmers who can help me out?

EDIT: I have picked up the undead src files stream and related files, but I am now having an int property issue. According to the forum where I found this code, it worked at the time of posting 4 years ago so I can't imagine that the 'files.sort' is inherently problematic.

```
import std.stdio;
import std.file;
import std.conv;
import std.stream;
import std.bitmanip;

void main(string args[]){
    Stream pkfile = new BufferedFile(args[1],FileMode.In);

    int headersize;
    int counter = 0;
    int filecount;
    int throwaway;
    int offset;

    pkfile.read(headersize);
    pkfile.read(filecount);
    writefln("Count is : " ~ to!string(filecount));
    int[] files = new int[filecount];
    for(int x = 0; x < filecount; x++)
    {
        pkfile.read(throwaway);
        pkfile.read(offset);
        files[x] = offset + (headersize + 4);
    }

    files = files.sort;
    for(int x =0; x < filecount; x++)
    {
        pkfile.seekSet(cast(long)files[x]);
        long len;
        pkfile.read(len);
        int newlen = cast(int)len;
        ubyte[] ogg = new ubyte[newlen];
        pkfile.read(ogg);
        string outname = getcwd() ~"/"~ to!string(counter) ~ ".ogg";
        Stream oggout = new BufferedFile(outname,FileMode.OutNew);
        oggout.write(shiftL(ogg,newlen));
        oggout.close();
        writefln("Creating file " ~ to!string(counter) ~".ogg");
        counter++;
    }
}

ubyte[] shiftL(ubyte[] ogg,int ogglength){
    ubyte[] temp = new ubyte[ogglength];
    for(int x = 0;x < ogglength;x++){
        temp[x] = cast(byte)(ogg[x]-1);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: You can use std.algorithm's sort (``files.sort();``).

Comment: Do I import std.algorithm.sorting for that? When I do that and make the suggested change from sort to sort(), I get the error 'cannot implicitly convert expression sort(files) of type SortedRange!(int[], "a < b") to int[]'

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to grab a copy of [std.stream](https://github.com/dlang/undeaD/blob/master/src/undead/stream.d).

But for rewriting, I'd read the full file into memory and then slice it as you read bits of it.

Comment: So I went and got "std.stream and friends", namely undead/internal/file.d, undead/utf.d, and undead/doformat.d, but now I'm getting the following error: 

extractor.d(27): Error: no property sort for type int[]

Comments on the forum where the code was posted suggest that it worked without flaw at time of posting, so I'm hesitant to say it's an inherent problem with the line. Has sort ever been a property of int[]?

Comment: `sort` used to be defined on all arrays, but has been replaced with [`std.algorithm.sorting.sort`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_sorting.html).

Comment: So what do I need to import to make (27) 'files.sort' or 'files.sort()' work?